# ASP.NET Content Web Form - content from placeholder disappears

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm attempting to set a class on the body tag in my asp.net site which uses a master page and content web forms. I simply want to be able to do this by adding a bodycssclass property (see below) to the content web form page directive.

It works through the solution below but when i attempt to view Default.aspx the **Content1** control loses its content. **Any ideas why?**

Here is how I'm doing it. I have a master page with the following content:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" ... %>
<html><head>...</head>
<body id=ctlBody runat=server>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

it's code behind looks like:

```
public partial class Site : MasterPageBase
{
    public override string BodyCssClass
    {
        get { return ctlBody.Attributes["class"]; }
        set { ctlBody.Attributes["class"] = value; }
    }
}
```

it inherits from:

```
public abstract class MasterPageBase : MasterPage
{
    public abstract string BodyCssClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

my default.aspx is defined as:

```
<%@ Page Title="..." [master page definition etc..] bodycssclass="home" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
  Some content
</asp:Content>
```

the code behind for this file looks like:

```
public partial class Default : PageBase { ... }
```

and it inherits from :

```
public class PageBase : Page
{
    public string BodyCssClass
    {
        get
        {
            MasterPageBase mpbCurrent = this.Master as MasterPageBase;
            return mpbCurrent.BodyCssClass;
        }
        set
        {
            MasterPageBase mpbCurrent = this.Master as MasterPageBase;
            mpbCurrent.BodyCssClass = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to `MasterPageBase mpbCurrent = this.Master as MasterPageBase;`, if I comment that and the following line out the content remains. Seems like referencing the Master page at that point is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me now...

```
public class PageBase : Page
{
    public string BodyCssClass
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPageBase mpbCurrent = this.Master as MasterPageBase;
        mpbCurrent.BodyCssClass = BodyCssClass;

        base.OnLoadComplete(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Was banging my head for a hour then found your answer. Wonder why it works like this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the MasterType directive to your content page? Like so:

I recommend doing that anyway. Let's see if that helps you...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx